# Using custom jquery with jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have some custom jquery events I'm using within a jquery mobile site.  I'm including this custom.js before the jquery-mobile include -- as I believe this is the correct course of action.  jquery is being included first.  These files are being included on every page.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/components/m/js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

When I load my main index page, there's no elements using custom.js.  It's when I click on a page to go in deeper is where my problem is.  So I click a link to view an artist which has an event in custom.js  When jquery mobile does it's thing, my click event does not work.

However, if I reload the page, the custom click event will work just fine.

What am I missing?  Should i be using .live('click' as opposed to just .click?

Comment: Have you already tried using live('click')? Seems to me that would be the easiest way to find out.

Comment: I've noticed live('click') works somewhat as it triggers, but my ajax call will not work.  But if I refresh the page, it'll work just fine.  So baby steps.

Comment: Is that deeper page, by any chance, a multipage (contains more than one `div` tag with `data-role="page"`) jQM file?

Comment: Also show relevant code where you define your click handlers including outer page-wide handlers where you put them.

Comment: Mike if you want send me your custom js file to my mail and I will tell you what is a problem. I think I already know, every event you want to bind to an page element or a page (except page events) must be bound inside a proper jQM page event.

Answer (score 0):

After speaking with Gajotres (via email from the comments above), we came to the following conclusion.

My custom js file actually had to come AFTER the jQM file.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/components/m/js/custom-alt.js"></script>
```

Also, this is what my custom js file looks like:

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function() {
    var btnAddComment = $('#btn-addcomment');

    // register functions with jqm framework
    $(btnAddComment).bind('touchstart mousedown', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        clickCommentAdd(); 
    }); 

    function clickCommentAdd() {
        $("#form-comment").toggle();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Previously, I was using "mobileint" instead of "pageint" and as quoted from Gajotres:

> Reason for this is, pageinit event works only when jQuery Mobile js file is loaded. I also see you have tried to use mobileinit even. Well
>   that event is supposed to be used before jQuery Mobile js file (so far so good) but you can use it to bind and click event because you
>   need loaded jQM js file to initialize page elements.